# FAA Regulations for Passenger Aircraft

Tags: faa-regulations, safety

Does the FAA have regulations for aircraft that carry passengers over large oceans regarding number of engines and flying range of the aircraft ?

Comment: @J.Hougaard: While relevant here, ETOPS is not the full answer. You need to add minimum reserve rules and maximum distance to alternates rules for a full answer.

Comment: I really don't agree with the duplicate one (I cast for too broad, but the system uses majority votes), however at the very best this is either unclear or too broad. Please review the FAR's regarding commercial operations and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: The FAA has lots of regulations that would apply here: 14 CFR parts 25, 91 and 121 at least, plus whatever is required by the airline's OpSpec (which are approved by the FAA). That means your question is very broad, you'll get a better answer if you can make it more specific and limited.

Answer (score -1):

Definitive answer: yes, it does.  Lots & lots of them.

Comment: you could at least mention some, otherwise it does not really help the OP.